# Highcharts: Set programmatically the crosshair on the first xAxis item

Tags: highcharts, hover

I have a charts having two stacked series. This chart is a bar chart that turns to a column chart when a certain amount of item is reached.

I'd like to highlight the first item (same as the mouse hover effect but without the tooltip being shown). So the first item will have a box exactly the same as the mouse hover effect (highchart calls it "crosshair").

How can I achieve that ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I found how to set the 'crosshair' and now how to "keep" it (reset it).
Indeed, what I want it :

1. Initialisation : the first item has this crosshair hover effect activated by default
2. Hover on another item
3. Leave the focus (blur) of the chart
4. Then reapply step #1

Set crosshair on 1st xAxis item:

```
let myChart= Highcharts.chart('myContainer', {
data: {
    table: $sourceTableId,
    endColumn : 2
},
chart: {
    type: $nbItems >= 1 + $nbBenchmarks + 5 ? 'bar' : 'column',
    events: {
        'load': function() {
            if (this.series[0].data.length > 0) {
                let points = [],
                    series = this.series;

                // Setting points to be selected
                for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
                    points.push(series[i].data[0]);
                }
                this.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(null, points[1]); // Show the crosshair
            }
        }
    }
},
yAxis:{        
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 1);
        }
    },
    reversedStacks: false
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal', // for mode : column
        dataLabels: {       // for mode : column
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal', // for mode : bar
        dataLabels: {       // for mode : bar
            enabled: true
        }
    }
} });
```

Try to reactive crosshair ou mouseOut (of the point)...for the moment code is quite duplicated just to make thins working :

```
$('#myContainer').mouseleave(function() {
        let chart = myChart;

        if (chart.series[0].data.length > 0) {
            let points = [],
                series = chart.series;

            // Setting points to be selected
            for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
                points.push(series[i].data[0]);
            }

            // timeout is necessary to let finish
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Show the crosshair
                chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(null, points[0])
            }, 0); 
        }
    });
```

Working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cjpr4o8n/1/) (no jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `setState('hover')` on the first point:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.series[0].points[0].setState('hover');
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3vr9k8tx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

Comment: Thanks, actually it's not the 'hover' that I want to set but the 'crosshair'. 
In the meantime, I found it but not yet satisfied. See my answer below.

Comment: Hi @pti_jul, I don't see any effect with using your code in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nbj9egwL/ Could you update the example to show your current state?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I've updated my answer with a sample demo I updated with my solution fitting my needs. The "hover" state is not what I was looking for (My tooltip series are shared so the hover highlight is not conveniant + requires user action. I needed  to have this highlight applied on load directly without any action